# Socket.io + Angular - Sending Private Messages

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

When the user joins I send back an object with their **nickname** and **socketid**. Then I'm able to display all users and send messages.

What I want to do is when the user's name is clicked, send a message only to that user. This is the full repo [chat app using socket.io](https://github.com/jakblak/socketio)

**Edit**

I'm updating this to just ask for some help on how to grab or correctly filter to extract the socketid from my array which contains an object.

I'm using this to filter for the correct user based on a click event:

```
 $scope.sendLike = function(e) {
  var toLike = $scope.users.filter(function(e) {
    return e.nickname
  });
  var likeObj = {
    from: $scope.mynickname,
    like: toLike
  }
  socket.emit('send-like', likeObj);
}
```

I get back an array for my user that looks like:

```
[ { nickname: 'me', socketid: '/#nadkl897dasd' } ]
```

And I need to return just the value of my **socketid**

Comment: You can let the user who clicked the name make a new room and send the other user a notification that the user started a private session

Comment: thanks, maybe I will try something like that if I can't figure it out this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a similar application below are few links which has helped a lot -

http://www.tamas.io/advanced-chat-using-node-js-and-socket-io-episode-1/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8o8-Q_-Qfk&ebc=ANyPxKo9fyO9bAywLGR9_p-_IcmkuQMK8Rfrk84qCON25JXlRReI8z3_5Qir9U1QNp6Sgm1RVkFfG-RHJ2y7ApVqd5gRVTarAQ#t=2.797

Below is the code I have used :

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
users = {};

server.listen(3002);
console.log(__dirname)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('new user', function (data, callback) {
    if (data in users)
        callback(false);
    //if (data === 'rahul') {
    //    socket.disconnect('unauthorized'); // for unauthorised users
    //    console.log('unauthorized');
    //}
    else {

        callback(true);
        socket.nickname = data;
        users[socket.nickname] = socket;
        updateNicknames()
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    if (!socket.nickname) return;

    console.log('disconnect' + users[socket.nickname]);
    delete users[socket.nickname];
    updateNicknames()

});

function updateNicknames() {
    io.sockets.emit('username',Object.keys(users))
}

socket.on('send message', function (data) {
    //io.sockets.emit('new message', data); // used to send to everyone
    var ind = data.indexOf(' ');
    if(ind !== -1){
        var name = data.substring(0, ind);
        console.log(name);
        var msg = data.substring(ind + 1);
        console.log(msg);
        if(name in users){
            users[name].emit('whisper',{msg:msg, nick:socket.nickname});
         }
    }
});
});
```

Do let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I ended up using a lodash method.  Great library for manipulating arrays/objects.  This is using the ng-lodash helper library.

```
  $scope.sendLike = function(e) {
  var toLike = $scope.users.filter(function(f) {
    if(e.socketid === f.socketid)
    return f.socketid;
  });
  // $scope.socketid = e.socketid;
  var result = lodash.get(toLike, '[0].socketid');
  var likeObj = {
    from: $scope.mynickname,
    like: result
  }
  socket.emit('send-like', likeObj);
}
```

**My HTML**

```
      <li class="user"
       ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
       <a href="#" ng-click="sendLike(user)">
```